# Android: Click event for Status bar notification

Tags: android, notifications

I've got the following code to create a status bar notification:

```
public void txtNotification(int id, String msg){
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(android.R.drawable.sym_action_email, msg, System.currentTimeMillis());

    // The PendingIntent will launch activity if the user selects this notification
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
    intent.putExtra("yourpackage.notifyId", id);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "title", msg, contentIntent);

    manager.notify(id, notification);
}
```

When the notification is clicked, I want to call a method, preferrably with access to the id of the notification.

Thanks in advance,

Tim

(EDIT: I updated my code after reading the first answer, but I still don't know how to listen for the intent)

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I updated my answer a few days ago. Please let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've read some stuff there, but that was mostly just tech specs about objects. That page is very useful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the best way for you to handle a click on the notification (maybe the only way?) is to define a method within the class your PendingIntent calls (MainActivity in this case). You can modify your intent before passing it into getActivity() to include the id of the notification:

```
// The PendingIntent will launch activity if the user selects this notification
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
intent.putExtra("yourpackage.notifyId", id);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, 0);
```

Then watch for this intent within MainActivity and call the method you defined within the class to handle the notification. You can extract the id from the incoming Intent.

**Update:**

In order for your Activity to handle the notification, you'll need to first define the Activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, including any intent filters you need. Then in your Activity's onStart() you can extract the extras from the incoming intent, and act upon that data. This is a high level overview, so I suggest you read parts of the Dev Guide to familiarize yourself with the concepts. The following page is a good place to start:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Also "yourpackage" should be replaced with the name of the package that includes your Class, such as "com.project.foo".

Comment: Thank you, I am quite new to Android developing and I never actually used intents before. How would I set up a listener?

Comment: Form me, without `packagename` it worked. Thank you! :)

Comment: If you have a lot of different notification types you could make life easy by supplying an array if intents with the first being an empty one just collecting the click. That is the 3rd parameter should be Intent[].

Answer (score 2):

For dummies like myself:
Getting this yourpackage.notifyId at MainActivity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle intent_extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (intent_extras != null && intent_extras.containsKey("yourpackage.notifyId"))
        {
          //Do the codes
        }

}
```

In my case - used it to determine who is opening my mainactivity, user or a call from notification, cteated by GcmIntentService...
P.S. I've used names without "youpackage", works fine too.

Comment: Using names without a "yourpackage" prefix works but be aware that this is a risk since extras of other intents could contain an equal key which then would probably lead to wrong behaviour... So better use a package namespace.