# Get id of particular push notification from multiple push notification on statusbar in android

Tags: android, push-notification

In my application, I am generate 3 push notification. Below is my code..

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message, String type)
{

    if (type.equals("HR_ABSENCES"))
    {
        int icon = R.drawable.logo_push;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManagerAbsence = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = null;
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Worklist.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("PushNotificationTypeAbsence", "ABSENCE");
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManagerAbsence.notify(0, notification);
    }
    else if (type.equals("TICKET_APPROVAL"))
    {
        int icon = R.drawable.logo_push;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManagerTicket = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = null;
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Worklist.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("PushNotificationTypeTicket", "TICKET");
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManagerTicket.notify(1, notification);
    }
    else if (type.equals("TIMESHEET_APPROVAL"))
    {
        int icon = R.drawable.logo_push;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManagerTimesheet = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = null;
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Worklist.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("PushNotificationTypeTimesheet", "TIMESHEET");
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManagerTimesheet.notify(2, notification);
    }
}
```

[image]

My question is that all notifications are properly displayed.  Click on a notification, and a web service is called. But I am not able to find out that which notification was clicked. I added intent to the notification.  But I always get the first notification's value. Is there any way to know which notification was selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by request code in pending intent

change the second request code value, by that you can differentiate it

```
     PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, -------, notificationIntent, 0);
```

just checkout the below link

[Android: Click event for Status bar notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345279/android-click-event-for-status-bar-notification)